# Amazon Web Services PHP FTP Get

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I am using Elastic Beanstalk and have deployed my application to Worker Tier.

Part of my application is to connect to remote ftp and download remote files using PHP.

It works without a problem on localhost. When I execute the PHP script on amazon web services, I get this weird error:

`IP1 = XXX.XX.XX.XX`
`IP2 = XX.XX.XXX.XXX`

`PHP Error[2]: ftp_get(): I won't open a connection to IP1 (only to IP2)`

Application runs on a single instance (non-balanced), on default VPC.

What is really weird is that `IP1` does not match to the host I'm trying to download the file from (ie `example.com`). Could that be the Internet Gateway IP?

Same application also downloads pictures and connects to APIs, it's definitely connected to the Internet.

I assume the VPC routing configuration won't allow instance to talk to other protocols with target `0.0.0.0/0` (ie any location) but only HTTP.

- VPC ID: `vpc-53cc2236`
- Network ACL: `acl-c850baad`
- State: `available`
- Tenancy: `Default`
- VPC CIDR: `172.31.0.0/16`
- DNS resolution: `yes`
- DHCP options set: `dopt-f2998e90`
- DNS hostnames: `yes`
- Route table: `rtb-2b64914e`

EC2 instance belongs to **subnet-1250b265:**

- Route Table: `rtb-2b64914e`
- `Destination:` 172.31.0.0/16 `target:` local
- `Destination:` 0.0.0.0/0 `target:` igw-a48199c6

Route table **rtb-2b64914e**:

```
Destination   | Target       | Status | Propagated
172.31.0.0/16 | local        | Active | No
0.0.0.0/0     | igw-a48199c6 | Active |No
```

There are also two other subnets, `subnet-ab0003ed`, and `subnet-96f335f3` which belong to same route table as `subnet-1250b265`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some folks suggested that firewall might block access to FTP. That wasn't the case for me, proper ports were open.

I tried ftp_connect, ftp_get but didn't work (tried with PASV on/off).

I tried to curl ftp download the file but got: `No Route to Host` error.

Then, I tried to curl ftp download the file using php, but I only got an empty file.

Since I have SSH access to the server, I tried to get the file using SCP but got a weird error saying `Warning: ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file`.

I also found a [PHP patch for this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55651) but didn't want to mess patch PHP version on AWS.

I ended up using [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) which worked fine - no trouble there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and resolved it by using passive mode.

```
ftp> pass
Passive mode on.
```

In ruby, the code ended up being:

```
Net::FTP.open(host) do |ftp|
  ftp.login(user, pwd)
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.put(output_filename, "#{target_dir]}/#{target_filename}")
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work. The server I'm trying to connect won't work with Passive mode on.